# Show notification on bluetooth device disconnection

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am working with the communication within a BLE device in my app. I would like to show a notification when the device gets disconnected. I did research on the Internet and I came to a rough implementation but without succeeding. Can anyone give me directions? This is my code.

```
public void disconnect() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Bluetooth not initialized");
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    addNotification();
    //mBluetoothGatt.close();
}

private void addNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
    .setContentTitle("STATE DEVICE")
    .setContentText("Device Disconnected!")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: Use LocalBroadcast receivers to get response when BLE is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is using **onConnectionStateChange** method of [BluetoothGattCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)) instead of showing the notification after calling disconnect()

1) Define the bluetooth gatt callback:

```java
private BluetoothGattCallback callback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            if (newState == STATE_DISCONNECTED){
                // show notification
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) Use pass the callback to your connectGatt method:

```java
myDevice.connectGatt(this, true, callback);
```